# Combine n sheets in one sheet, side by side

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to transfer several Excel sheets into one. These should be pasted side by side.

For example sheet1-table A to D, sheet2-table E to G, sheet3-table H to J, and so on.

The tables (of different sizes) are not pasted side by side.

I found code and tried to adjust it:

```vb
Sub CombineSheetsNextToEachOther()
On Error GoTo eh
'declare variables to hold the objects required
   Dim wbDestination As Workbook
   Dim wbSource As Workbook
   Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Dim strSheetName As String
   Dim strDestName As String
   Dim iRws As Integer
   Dim iCols As Integer
   Dim totRws As Integer
   Dim totCols As Integer
   Dim strEndRng As String
   Dim rngSource As Range
'turn off the screen updating to speed things up
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'first create new destination workbook
   Set wbDestination = Workbooks.Add
'get the name of the new workbook so you exclude it from the loop below
   strDestName = wbDestination.Name
'now loop through each of the workbooks open to get the data
   For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
      If wb.Name <> strDestName And wb.Name <> "PERSONAL.XLSB" Then
         Set wbSource = wb
         For Each sh In wbSource.Worksheets
'get the number of rows and columns in the sheet
            sh.Activate
            ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Activate
            iRws = ActiveCell.Row
            iCols = ActiveCell.Column
'set the range of the last cell in the sheet
            strEndRng = sh.Cells(iRws, iCols).Address
'set the source range to copy
            Set rngSource = sh.Range("A1:" & strEndRng)
'find the last column in the destination sheet
           wbDestination.Activate
           Set wsDestination = ActiveSheet
           wsDestination.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Select
           totCols = ActiveCell.Column
'add a column to paste on the next column right
           If totCols <> 1 Then totCols = totCols + 1
           rngSource.Copy Destination:=wsDestination.Range("A" & totCols)
      Next sh
   End If
   Next wb
'now close all the open files except the one you want
   For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
      If wb.Name <> strDestName And wb.Name <> "PERSONAL.XLSB" Then
         wb.Close False
      End If
   Next wb
'clean up the objects to release the memory
   Set wbDestination = Nothing
   Set wbSource = Nothing
   Set wsDestination = Nothing
   Set rngSource = Nothing
   Set wb = Nothing
'turn on the screen updating when complete
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Exit Sub
eh:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one mistake in your code.

The code line 44 `rngSource.Copy Destination:=wsDestination.Range("A" & totCols)`  pastes the data on column "A", row "totCols"—which is the oposite of what you want.

Instead, you should use `rngSource.Copy Destination:=wsDestination.Cells(1, totCols)`.

On this 2nd version you are using row "1" and column "totCols", which is a dynamic number indicating the next column to paste information.

Please find bellow the full code, running well for me:

```
Sub CombineSheetsNextToEachOther()
On Error GoTo eh
'declare variables to hold the objects required
   Dim wbDestination As Workbook
   Dim wbSource As Workbook
   Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Dim strSheetName As String
   Dim strDestName As String
   Dim iRws As Integer
   Dim iCols As Integer
   Dim totRws As Integer
   Dim totCols As Integer
   Dim strEndRng As String
   Dim rngSource As Range
'turn off the screen updating to speed things up
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'first create new destination workbook
   Set wbDestination = Workbooks.Add
'get the name of the new workbook so you exclude it from the loop below
   strDestName = wbDestination.Name
'now loop through each of the workbooks open to get the data
   For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
      If wb.Name <> strDestName And wb.Name <> "PERSONAL.XLSB" Then
         Set wbSource = wb
         For Each sh In wbSource.Worksheets
'get the number of rows and columns in the sheet
            sh.Activate
            ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Activate
            iRws = ActiveCell.Row
            iCols = ActiveCell.Column
'set the range of the last cell in the sheet
            strEndRng = sh.Cells(iRws, iCols).Address
'set the source range to copy
            Set rngSource = sh.Range("A1:" & strEndRng)
'find the last column in the destination sheet
           wbDestination.Activate
           Set wsDestination = ActiveSheet
           wsDestination.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Select
           totCols = ActiveCell.Column
'add a column to paste on the next column right
           If totCols <> 1 Then totCols = totCols + 1
           rngSource.Copy Destination:=wsDestination.Cells(1, totCols)
      Next sh
   End If
   Next wb
'now close all the open files except the one you want
   For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
      If wb.Name <> strDestName And wb.Name <> "PERSONAL.XLSB" Then
         wb.Close False
      End If
   Next wb
'clean up the objects to release the memory
   Set wbDestination = Nothing
   Set wbSource = Nothing
   Set wsDestination = Nothing
   Set rngSource = Nothing
   Set wb = Nothing
'turn on the screen updating when complete
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Exit Sub
eh:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```